# Windows App Store - use of "results" view for my own search

Tags: search, windows-8

I have implemented a search mechanism in my app. The user fill a textbox and then click on a button. is there a way to use the nice results view of Microsoft? i'm talking about the view you can see in the image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you few resources, please check it out and let us know if you face any problem.

[Guidelines and checklist for search (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465233.aspx)

[Quickstart: Adding search to an app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465238.aspx)

[Windows 8 and the future of XAML: Part 4: Contracts in WinRT/Windows 8](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-and-the-future-of-XAML-Part-4-Contracts-in-WinRT-Windows-8.aspx)

[Search contract sample from MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5)

Answer (score 0):

That's just a page and layout that someone created for that given app... given the Contoso branding it's some sample, though I don't immediately recognize it.  I assume you saw the image, but don't have the source to it?

In Visual Studio, within an existing app you can use the Add>New Item dialog and select **Search Contract** to include a template page (with grid, filter combo box, etc.) to get you jumpstarted.

In the [Windows 8 Camp Training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29854), there is a fairly polished sample - Contoso Cookbook - that also includes a filtered search page, so that may be helpful as a start too.

Comment: i've added the search contract template page. now, i'm connecting to a webservice and it gives me some results...how can i fill these results in the Contract Page?